# In Word 2016, how can all Paragraph Numbering be deleted all at once?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

The numbering above was generated via `Home > Paragraph > Numbering or Multilevel List (I cannot remember which)`.

[This comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1060995/continue-numbering-fails-to-continue-all-numbering-below-the-one-that-i-right#comment1491078_1060995) suggests my fault in failing to number correctly; so I am trying to delete all numbers simultaneously before I select `Multilevel List` this time.

Per the screenshot above:

1. when I right-click on the numbering, the `Cut` option has already been faded and cannot be clicked.
2. left-clicking the numbering turns it grey, but pressing `Delete` on my keyboard deletes only `1.` Inefficiently and agonisingly, I had to repeat pressing `Delete` to delete each number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the range of numbers (and text if there is any for each number) and click the Numbering button, and it will turn off numbering.

The numbers themselves are special text with predefined rules and margins, separate from other text. That's why you can't copy or cut just the numbers, they're "locked in" in a way, with a toggle button to turn them off and on.

[Update from further comments below]

If your selection includes non-numbered text, then the Numbering button won't appear activated. If you click it anyway, it will make the whole selection numbered, and then if you click it again, everything will be un-numbered. (If anything winds up with an extra indentation, press the Decrease Indent button next to the Multilevel List button.)

You could also select only the text that is numbered and then click the Numbering button to remove the numbering. Non-congruous selecting might benefit you there (Ctrl-clicking instead of Shift-clicking).

Comment: Sorry, but this does not appear to resolve my problem. After I clicked 'Numbering', only the first number disappeared: this disappearance equals 2 in my post above.

Comment: Are you clicking on the numbers themselves? Instead you should be just highlighting the range of text, then pressing the numbering button. Like this: [link](http://s16.postimg.org/f7cwfsi1h/Screen_Shot_2016_04_06_at_4_17_57_PM.png)

Comment: Thanks. Your screenshot helped! But this approach only deletes the numbering in paragraphs? When I highlighted the entire range of my Word document that contains Tables, the 'Numbering' button was no longer activated and so could not longer be pressed.

Comment: If your selection includes text (or tables) that are not numbered, then the Numbering button won't appear activated. But if you click it anyway, it will make everything you have selected numbered, and then if you click it again, everything will be un-numbered. (If anything winds up with an extra indentation, just press the Decrease Indent button next to the Multilevel List button.)  You could also select only the text that is numbered and then click the Numbering button to remove the numbering. Non-congruous selecting might benefit you there (Ctrl-clicking instead of Shift-clicking).

Comment: Thanks again. Your latest comment above resolved my problem; wish you to include it in your answer directly?

Comment: Glad to hear it! I have updated my answer with that info.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered another solution:

1. Highlight all text, tables, and material to be deleted, using 'SHIFT'.
2. Then proceed to `Home > Paragraph > Multilevel List > List None`. Clicking `List None` should remove all numbering. Notice that I refer only to `Multilevel List` and not `Numbering`, because I saw the following admonition on [Shauna Kelly's website](http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) (but please correct me if it is wrong):

[image]